# VB.NET System.IO.File.Copy question

Tags: vb.net

I'm using System.IO.File.Copy to copy a file to c$ on a remote server. I need to specify username/password for the connection. Is there a simple way to do this? I had hoped that System.IO.File.Copy would accept credentials as an argument but it doesn't. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute simplest thing to do is to add this routine to your code then call it right before your File.Copy:

```
Private Sub Open_Remote_Connection(ByVal strComputer As String, ByVal strUsername As String, ByVal strPassword As String)
    '//====================================================================================
    '//using NET USE to open a connection to the remote computer
    '//with the specified credentials. if we dont do this first, File.Copy will fail
    '//====================================================================================
    Dim ProcessStartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    ProcessStartInfo.FileName = "net"
    ProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "use \\" & strComputer & "\c$ /USER:" & strUsername & " " & strPassword
    ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)

    '//============================================================================
    '//wait 2 seconds to let the above command complete or the copy will still fail
    '//============================================================================
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant add credentials to the system.io.file but there seems to be a workaround here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1283577.aspx/1

Snippet from above link:

```
using (System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = System.Security.Pricipal.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(userTokenptr))

{
 //do your IO operations
 ctx.Undo();     
}
```

Converted to vb.net:

```
Using ctx As System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext = System.Security.Pricipal.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(userTokenptr)
    'do your IO operations       
     ctx.Undo()
End Using
```

Credits goes to [Ganeshyb](http://forums.asp.net/members/Ganeshyb.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. And WOW. This is unbelievably complex for something that should obviously be a builtin function of the Copy method. Is this the only way? I just gotta believe that MS would have thought of this and included a much simpler way.

Comment: Also check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6485ct6t(vs.71).aspx (for more complex stuff) :)

Comment: And here are another solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/b732f49a-5aa8-4a9d-8f88-35d7f235a082/

Comment: If some of the examples works for you, just post it as an full answer here.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net", "use \\" & strComputer & "\c$ /USER:" & strUsername & " " & strPassword)

Comment: Add that as an real answer to your question, that way everyone can see that it has been answered.